# Showing runtime error in printing

Tags: c, list

When i am printing linked list , i get runtime error

```
#include stdio.h
#include stddef.h

typedef struct
{
    int info;
    struct DEMO1 *next;
} DEMO1;

void insertatlast(DEMO1 * p, int o);

void printl(DEMO1 * p);

int main()
{
    int temp;
    DEMO1 *head = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        while (1)
        {
            printf("ENTER 0 to exit");
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            if (temp == 0)
                break;
            insertatlast(head, temp);
        }

    printl(head);
    return 0;
}

void insertatlast(DEMO1 * head, int data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        DEMO1 *node = (DEMO1 *) (malloc(sizeof(DEMO1)));

        node->info = data;
        node->next = 0;
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        DEMO1 *temp;

        temp = head;

        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        DEMO1 *node = (DEMO1 *) (malloc(sizeof(DEMO1)));

        node->info = data;
        node->next = 0;
        temp->next = node;
    }
}

void printl(DEMO1 * head)
{

    DEMO1 *temp;

    temp = head;
    printf("%d", temp->info);
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf(":) %d\n", temp->info);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `insertatlast(DEMO1 *head,int data) {` , `head` is value on stack. `head = node` not change original `head`.

Comment: `include stdio.h`… does your preprocessor preprocess this?

Comment: `printl` will crash if passed a NULL pointer.

Comment: @all for #include<stdio.h> i wrote this in my machine , here in stackoverflow i am new so learning how to format , please try to avoid them , and try to answer the question

Comment: now i am editing that,  it is showing add more text before u downvoted my question :(

Comment: @mbratch I said i am new to stackoverflow , i am learning to format , when i did copy paste , text inside <> did not display in preview , so i removed <> , and thought it will be understood to add <>

Comment: OK, no problem. You can copy/paste the code in, then you want to make it "literal" code by selecting all of it and clicking the `{}` at the top of the edit box. That will indent everything 4 spaces which is what triggers the "code formatting". Inline formatting (when referring to variables and such within your regular text) is with the "back ticks".

Comment: You might want to read the stackoverflow Help section which gives guidelines. One reason you can get a down vote is if you post a bunch of code and just say, "help me fix my problem" and have no other details indicating debug effort and information that narrows it down.

Comment: I will do that next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `head` is NULL, `head` is changed within the `insertatlast()` function only and not in `main()`. `return head` to update `head` in `main()` also.

```
DEMO1* insertatlast(DEMO1 * head, int data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        DEMO1 *node = (DEMO1 *) (malloc(sizeof(DEMO1)));

        node->info = data;
        node->next = 0;
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        DEMO1 *temp;

        temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        DEMO1 *node = (DEMO1 *) (malloc(sizeof(DEMO1)));

        node->info = data;
        node->next = 0;
        temp->next = node;
    }

    return head;
}


int main()
{
    int temp;
    DEMO1 *head = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        while (1)
        {
            printf("ENTER 0 to exit");
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            if (temp == 0)
                break;
            head=insertatlast(head, temp);
        }
    printl(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compile it (after fixing the missing `<>` in `#include`s, you can read some warning from your compiler — hopefully you have warnings enabled. Even if they doesn't solve your problem, it is a good habit to take a look at them.

Lines like

```
 DEMO1 *head = NULL;

 if (head == NULL)
```

should suggest you you are doing something wrong. The fact the if-body is executed, tell you alone that head is NULL when you call `insertatlast`. That's fine, you expect it. What you likely do not expect is that your `head` **is not** modified by the call to `insertatlast`: so when you call `printl`, head is NULL still, and calling

```
 `printl(NULL);`
```

is problematic, because of

```
  temp = head;
  ... temp->info ...
```

I guess someone told you that if you want to modify a value of a variable in the caller, you have to pass a pointer to that variable, and that since you have already a pointer, you get confused.

The fact is, a pointer is a variable too, and if you need to modify it, you *must* get the pointer to... a pointer.

```
DEMO1* head = NULL;

//...
insertatlast(&head, temp);
```

and your prototype for the insert would be

```
void insertatlast(DEMO1 **head, int data);
```

Then, you modify the caller variable (the `DEMO1*`), access it and so on, by using `*head` (don't forget that in `insertatlast` head has type `DEMO1**`, and so `*head` has type `DEMO1*`).

#### Note

Do not cast `malloc` return value; in C

```
 DEMO1* node = malloc(sizeof (DEMO1));
```

suffices.

Comment: I assigned head , address of node in insertatlast

Comment: @io10 modified answer, I hope it explains your error and misunderstanding of the fact you have the pointer - as BLUEPIXIE already pointed out